# Building virtual environment inside bash

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vpn, bittorrent

I'm setting up a homelab, and one of the things I want to do is set up a torrent client. The machine's hardware is dated, to say the least. The OS is ubuntu server.

Essentially, I only want to route torrent client traffic through my vpn, but leave everything else normal. The server is already running an openvpn server instance, and I think that might cause issues if I try to run a client on there as well. I also don't really want to configure a separate machine to act as a router. The best thing I've seen so far is to run the client and vpn connection inside a vm, and configure the routing in the vm to only allow vpn traffic out. That way if the connection dies I don't have unencrypted torrent traffic on my home network.

My question is: what's the best way to run a virtual environment inside bash/ubuntu? It'd have to be terminal only, and be able to transfer data between itself and the host os. 
Is there any easier way to do this, that has a failsafe in case of the vpn connection dropping?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest take a look at to docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task at hand, to run a single application that goes through a VPN client to reach the network, without affecting anything else running on the host, can be done quite efficiently and flexibly by running the program in a Docker container.

There is a learning curve to Docker, but it's an amazing technology that is worth learning for the long term.

At a high level, the steps would be:

- Install docker and familiarize yourself by running their hello world examples, etc.
- Prototype by instantiating an OS like Ubuntu 18.04 in a container and installing any necessary software. Note that the container can already reach the Internet.
- Create a Dockerfile so these construction steps can be iterated easily until they're perfected.
- Use the image to start a container with the target application whenever desired. Instantiating a container is near instantaneous.

So... I was typing out more and more detailed instructions, until eventually I realized I was going to finish the whole thing for practice, and ended up creating a Docker image that sets up OpenVPN Client and runs bit torrent software.

It's about 54 lines of Dockerfile and shell scripts. If you'd like to try it and use it as a prototype, it's already on GitHub:

https://github.com/curtmcd/docker-vpn-client

[image: docker-vpn-client logo]